# Astro load fonts dynamically

Tags: astrojs

I am trying to load an unknown amount of webfonts in Astro.

```
function getFonts() {
    return `
      ${global.font
                .map((item) => {
                    return `@font-face {
                font-family: ${item.name};
                src:    url(${item.url2}) format('woff2'),
                        url(${item.url1}) format('woff');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
                font-display: swap;
                }`;
                })
                .join('\n')}
  `;
}

const fonts = getFonts();
```

But as soon as I use {fonts} it in my head tag, I get either the error "unknown word" or simply the output {`${fonts}`} as a string. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [set:html](https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#sethtml) directive on a `<style>` tag like this:

```
<style set:html={fonts}/>
```

Comment: Thank you - sometimes the solution is right in front of your eyes...